# AngularJS Redirect removing #

Tags: angularjs, html, url, redirect, razor

I have in my a .cshtml file a view that has a button that "updates"
The update button works but I want to redirect to home directory.

In my .js file i first had

```
    success(function (data) {
        //Showing Success message
        alert("Incident Added");
        $location.path("\Home");
    })
```

The link went from /Home/Create to  /Home/Create#/Home and just stays there. I would like it to go back to my home directory. Essentially going back to the home view after Create.

I also tried this

```
        success(function (data) {
        //Showing Success message
        alert("Incident Added");
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $location.path("/Home");
        });
    })
```

And the url didn't add the #/Home afterwards but it stayed the same of /Home/Create and didnt' go to /Home. I would like to know what do I need to do to get it go back home. Or rather learn how to do redirects properly.

Comment: In your `app.config` you declare with `$routeProvider` you declare where to send user depending on what url user enters. What is the `templateUrl` for your `/home`? Here you can read more about `$routeParams` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your $routProvider has this set for home

```
  $routeProvider

    .when('/', { templateUrl:'home.html',controller:'CtrlHome'})
```

you should be able to just use

```
 $location.path("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

$location service designed for single page application it works with [$route service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) and easily be misunderstood

if you want a basic HTTP Redirect to MVC route (eg. your.app.com/Home) use $window.location

```
$window.location.href = "/Home";
```